# Upper bound on the operator norm of the inverse of the sum of two matrices

Tags: matrices, operator-theory, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ (typically random Gaussian) with $m<n$ and a matrix $W\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times n}$ with $N>n$. Moreover, I assume that $\exists C>0:\ \|W\|_{2\rightarrow2}\leq C$, where $\|\cdot\|_{2\rightarrow2}$ is the operator norm. What I want, is to upper bound the following quantity
\begin{equation}
\|(A^TA+\rho W^TW)^{-1}\|_{2\rightarrow2}
\end{equation}
in terms of $C$ and $\rho>0$ (of course I don't mind if $\|A\|_{2\rightarrow2}$ also appears in the estimate). Now, I know that if $A^TA$ is invertible and $\|(A^TA)^{-1}\|_{2\rightarrow2}\cdot\|W^TW\|_{2\rightarrow2}<1$, there exists an upper bound in terms of $\|(A^TA)^{-1}\|_{2\rightarrow2}$, $\|W^TW\|_{2\rightarrow2}$.

However, I wonder if there's something similar in the general case, where no other assumptions are made, except for $\|W\|_{2\rightarrow2}\leq C$ (and possibly an extra one for $A$, e.g. when we consider $A/\sqrt{m}$ instead of $A$).

Comment: Since you all of for both $A$ and $W$ to be singular (e.g. zero) there is no upper bound and indeed the existence of the inverse is not even guaranteed.

Comment: Note also that the rank of $A$ is at most $m$, so $A^TA$ is necessarily not invertible.

Comment: @Ruy Actually $(\|A^TA+\rho W^TW\|_{2\rightarrow2})^{-1}$ is guaranteed to exist, e.g. it appears in the ADMM algorithm for the generalised LASSO problem. But thanks anyway for the comments!